# Magento checkout page intermittently returning 404 error

Tags: checkout-page, 404

Thank you for your response.
My partner handles the backend techy stuff but is unable to work currently and I am trying to manage in meantime.
We use only paypal and it was set up so that once people reach checkout it directs them to a page on our site but linked to paypal - we don't handle any payment details.
I have seen it twice when I have tried multiple test purchases. Our nrmal checkout has option to pay by e-invoice if preferred (some people seem to prefer this) but when the error occurs, there is no e-invoice option and the page is definitely different layout to the usual page. I have tried 5-6 times in past couple of days to create the error so I can screenshot it but it has behaved normally each time.
Tbh, it's almost like there are two versions of the page and occasionally it shows the wrong version.  From memory, checkout page is normal but when customer clicks "next" after choosing payment type, it returns the 404 error.

Original message: We are on magento community 2.4.0 and for the past couple of months, (occasional) transactions have resulted in 404 error after checkout.
We don't get any notification of an order.
I looked on stack exchange and someone reported this with mageonto 2.3 but I wonder if the same issue could be causing our problem on 2.4 ?
I am unsure since most customers checkout without any issue but it seems to be happening more often in the past couple of weeks.
We use paypal as our payment processor - not sure if that's relevant.
Thank you for any help!

Comment: Do you use other payment method than PayPal ? Is it the native PayPal module ? When exactly does the 404 error happens, on the checkout page, when redirecting to PayPal (or other payment method), or when coming back from the payment platform ?

Comment: Thank you - I have added info in the original message.